# How to remove infinite values from dataframe?

Tags: r

I want to assign `Inf` values in the dataframe `exp` as `NA`.

```
exp <- as.data.frame(log2(exp))
exp[!is.finite(unlist(exp)),] <- NA
```

Traceback:

```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, !is.finite(unlist(exp)), , value = NA) : 
  non-existent rows not allowed
```

Data:

```
#> dput(exp[1:3,1:3])
structure(list(TCGA.4A.A93W.01A = c(48.3424, 2.2117, 0), TCGA.A4.7734.01A = c(43.8689, 
1.8499, 50.74), TCGA.A4.7997.01A = c(70.2027, 86.9447, 1.2938
)), row.names = c("A1BG", "A1CF", "A2BP1"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example dataframe doesn't have any non-finite values, but if it did, you could do this:

```
df[abs(df)==Inf] <- NA
```

Input:

```
df=data.frame(val1 = c(10, 20, Inf),val2 = c(3, -Inf, Inf))
```

Output:

```
  val1 val2
1   10    3
2   20   NA
3   NA   NA
```

Comment: `is.na(df) <- abs(df) == Inf`

Comment: i like it @onyambu, but I'll admit, it took me a moment to figure it out!

Answer (score 1):

Replacing all values in a frame can be done this way:

```r
expr
#       TCGA.4A.A93W.01A TCGA.A4.7734.01A TCGA.A4.7997.01A
# A1BG          5.595217        5.4551266        6.1334546
# A1CF          1.145156        0.8874473        6.4420262
# A2BP1             -Inf        5.6650516        0.3716146
expr[] <- lapply(expr, function(z) replace(z, !is.finite(z), z[NA][1]))
expr
#       TCGA.4A.A93W.01A TCGA.A4.7734.01A TCGA.A4.7997.01A
# A1BG          5.595217        5.4551266        6.1334546
# A1CF          1.145156        0.8874473        6.4420262
# A2BP1               NA        5.6650516        0.3716146
```

Answer (score 1):

`is.infinite()` doesn’t have a method for dataframes, so coerce to a matrix to index:

```r
exp[is.infinite(as.matrix(exp))] <- NA

exp
```

```r
      TCGA.4A.A93W.01A TCGA.A4.7734.01A TCGA.A4.7997.01A
A1BG          5.595217        5.4551266        6.1334546
A1CF          1.145156        0.8874473        6.4420262
A2BP1               NA        5.6650516        0.3716146
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with {dplyr}

```r
library(dplyr)

d <- structure(list(a = c(1, Inf, Inf, Inf, 2), b = c(Inf, 3, -Inf, -Inf, 3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

d %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~if_else(is.finite(.x), .x, NA_real_)))
#>    a  b
#> 1  1 NA
#> 2 NA  3
#> 3 NA NA
#> 4 NA NA
#> 5  2  3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>